# a note on the coordinate ring of quasi-affine variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an affine variety and $f$ be a polynomial in $k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ such that $Y=X\backslash Z(f)\neq\emptyset$, it's easy to see that $Y$ is a quasi-affine variety, which implies that $I(X)=I(Y)$, because $Y$ is dense in $X$. But how can we understand $A(Y)\cong A(X)_f$? (what does this really mean?) We know that since $f(P)\neq0$ for all $P\in Y$, then $f$ is a unit in $A(Y)$, by Hilbert's Nullstenatz. So $h/f^m\mapsto hg^m$, where $g$ is the inverse of $f$ in $A(Y)$.

Comment: What book are you familiar with?

Comment: For an analogy with complex geometry, you might think of $Y$ the open submanifold of $X$ where the function $f$ does not vanish, and hence if you consider 'functions on $Y$', the functions $g$ on $X$ trivially restricts to $Y$, i.e. $g/1$. Moreover, you can take quotient by $f$ now, so your ring is $A(X)_f$.